# MVC 4: How to add some specific URL directly to BundleConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to bind a virtual url (other than "jquery.js") in a `BundleConfig.`

example : `"www.xyz/xyz.js"`

I can't keep one JS file in my local folder, I have to access it directly from web.

I tried this link, but it couldn't help me. [Using CDN in MVC script bundle. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401387/using-cdn-in-mvc-script-bundle-what-am-i-missing)

Thanks.
Himanshu Pareek.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Js file (from Virtual URL) doesn't load. Getting error where I am using that file.

Comment: any update on it.. please??