# Get assets like css and js files from azure blob storage and register it using RegisterBundles in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Is it possible to get css/js files from azure blob storage and register it as part of a bundle using, "BundleConfig.RegisterBundles" ?

I tried something similar with no luck,

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/assets/js/site-{version}.js"));            
    }
```

"~/assets/js/site.js" is the virtual path to the blob and I've include a url rewrite rule in my web.config

```
    <rule name="Assest">
      <match url="^assets/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://azure.datafiles.com/assets/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401387/using-cdn-in-mvc-script-bundle-what-am-i-missing

Comment: I dont want to use CDN, is there a work around?

Comment: Azure is your CDN here.

Comment: If you want to use directly from azure blobs, you can use WebEssential or even Grunt/Gulp to concat and minify, then upload on Azure Blobs, and can reference it